# Stream google meet Audio/screen on YouTube Live

Tags: video-streaming, streaming, audio-streaming, youtube-livestreaming-api

Lets say someone at remote place who is not having much knowledge about computer, is giving some speech on google meet [well we managed to make him understand, how to join google meet :)]. I do not have anyone there who can take responsibility to manage on daily basis for free. I want to live stream as is (This will also allow me to overcome Google meet limit of 100 Participants). Need procedure or steps to stream google meet Audio or may be meeting screen.

Currently I managed to record the loopback device using Audacity but I have to later save/process/cut/filter and podcast it or create video & upload on YouTube. But now I want to stream it as is.

Comment: This question is off-topic. Please read about what is [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here and what questions you should [avoid asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).

Answer (score 0):

You can use OBS Studio to capture your browser window that displays your google meet to YouTube. You can refer the YouTube for detailed guide on OBS Studio.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I managed to live stream using OBS :) Quite easy setup.